# How to get a new column in the case in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with `startdate` and `enddate`.

where start date is greater than endate i need to calculate the total days as 30 otherwise (enddate - startdate)+1 ... how do  i create a case statement for it.

```
Select case when 'startdate >  enddate' then 30
when 'startdate >  enddate' then (fine_fatturazione - startdate )+1
end
as td from table1


startdate   enddate
04-10-2015  04-12-2015
10-07-2015  09-08-2015
05-12-2015  04-01-2016
07-02-2016  04-01-2016
```

Comment: do you have a sample from the table and an example of the results you looking to have?

Comment: `when 'startdate >  enddate'` is invalid. `'startdate >  enddate'` is a string constant, but the `when` clause expects a boolean. You need to use `when startdate >  enddate` (no single quotes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select case when table1.startdate >  table1.enddate then 30
else table1.enddate - table1.startdate + 1
end
as td 
from table1
```